# Android: Best practice for responsive user interfaces

Tags: java, android, message

I am quite new to Android and Java. Before I was working with C++ where the events where dispatched with messages. Now I would like to create the same user experience for Android platform and I would appreciate any of your suggestions or comments on what is the best way to bind events to user controls.

Here is an example from C++:

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_RECORD_START, &CMainFrame::OnRecordStart)//Method OnRecordStarts() executes on WM_RECORD_START_MESSAGE
```

...

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnRecordStart(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

        m_pNetworkCtrl->SetGeoLocationInfo();
        ...
}
```

...

```
void CMainFrame::RecordStart()
{
    PostMessage(WM_RECORD_START);
}
```

In the case above the method `RecordStart()` is bound to a `Button` (it is executed when a `Button` is pressed) and posts the message `WM_RECORD_START`. When the message `WM_RECORD_START` is received, the method `OnRecordStart()` is executed.

As mentioned before I would like to create a responsive user interface and am not sure if it would be good enough if the method `OnRecordStart()` is called directly from `RecordStart()`:

```
void RecordStart()
{
    OnRecordStart();
}
```

I would really appreciate any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can emulator the MFC style behavior in Android by using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to post a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) into the message queue.

Here is a brief example

```
class MyClass
{
    Handler m_myHandler;
    Runnable m_myRunnable;

    MyClass()
    {
        m_myHandler = new Handler();
        m_myRunnable = new RUnnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // do your stuff here
            }
        };
    }

    public void onclickListener(...)
    {
        // push the runnable into the message queue
        m_myHandler.post(m_myRUnnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 questions here.

1. How to bind controls. I use
   anonymous inner classes everywhere. It is a bit verbose to type in but auto completion makes it a snap.
2. how to make the UI responsive.
   The key is not to do anything time
   consuming in the UI thread. If it
   takes more than .1s, do the work in
   a worker thread and notify the UI to
   update when the task is done. The
   other thing is to make sure you
   don't generate a lot of garbage
   since the android GC is pretty primitive right now.

Answer (score 1):

For `Button`s I usually extend `Button` class and override `onTouchEvent()`

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) 
{
   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
   {
      setPressed(true);
   }
   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```